# Using PON as main substrate for fiddle leaf figs

Tags: houseplants

Is Lechuza pon a suitable substrate for fiddle leaf figs ?

I just received a fiddle leaf fig tree which is 3 plants in a single 36 cm nursery pot. I bought a self watering 43 cm pot and I am planning to repot.

[image: The plant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen many different members of the Ficus family including the [fiddle leaf fig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_lyrata) grown in similar substrates. The problems that could occur are:

- these plants get quite tall.  In the wild they grow up to 45 feet tall so indoors they need to be cut back frequently or they will be up to the ceiling.  So much top weight makes them harder to keep balanced
- all the hydroponic solutions for plants work better if the solution can be changed.  The old style indoor hydroponics using [baked clay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroponics#Expanded_clay_aggregate) were in pots that did not drain. The solution was never changed and became saturated with dissolved salts in low light situations

In your question I don't see any reason why you want to go with a hydroponic solution.  It's extra work and cost with the same result as these plants grow quite well in a soil less potting mix